# Is there any package for inclusion of data in vcd format?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot

I need to include some figures of simulated verilog waveforms in a report. The last 20 years I have typically made a ps/pdf printout from a waveform viewer (such as gtkwave), and included the postscript or pdf into LaTeX (using for instance the package pdfpages).

This works, but I could get higher quality reports by going directly from a vcd (value change data, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_change_dump) file to "something", probably using tikz? Googling for filters for data in vcd to inclusion into LaTeX draws a blank for me, hence this question.

Comment: What kind of files are these vcd files? How are they formatted?

Answer (score 1):

Gtkwave allows you to export in TIM format for use with TimingAnalyzer.  That should produce better documentation.